# ASP.net MVC Is it possible to modify a class object in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a newbie and creating a website where you can create your own custom quizes. Ive made a database that stores a class object mytests that consists of a name, and a list of questions parameter.

```
public class MyTests
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<MyQuestions> AllTestQuestions;

}
```

//using this object for questions

```
public class MyQuestions
{
    public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }
    public string MultipleChoiceCorrect { get; set; }
    public string MultipleChoiceB { get; set; }
    public string MultipleChoiceC { get; set; }
    public string MultipleChoiceD { get; set; }
    public string Answerexplanation { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using the default database code generated by visual studio. I have no problem adding this test object(mytest) to the database, but what I want to do is that on the edit.cshtml view I want to be able to add elements to the question list before returning the object to the database saved.

The problem is I don't know how to edit the model object from the view, or if this is even possible. I could maybe get it to work through a redirect? but I thought that adding the elements directly from the view would be easier. Is it possible to modify the model.object inside a view from the view (putting security concerns aside)?

For example model.title = something;
or
model.list.add()

Is anything like this possible?

If this question is not clear please let me know and I will try to clarify in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to edit the model from within the view.

From within your .cshtml file specify the view model using the `@model` declaration, then edit the model like so:

```
@model Namespace.For.MyTests

@Model.name = "Hello World";

<p>@Model.name</p>
```

Whilst this would work, it's not really what the view is for so I wouldn't recommend it.

The view is about presenting your data, not mutating it - that should be done in the controller, or domain layer. As soon as the user leaves the page then your changes will be lost due to the stateless nature of the web (.NET MVC passes data to the view from the controller, then ends the request).

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to know. I didn't know this was possible because everything I've read insists on doing these kinds of assignments in other ways. Thank you.

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me as it's not really a common way of doing things, but it is possible. If this helped you out then I'd appreciate it if you marked it as the correct answer and provided an upvote if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done at the controller level. You could do it on a view but it's not what the view is for.

Your issue is that if the page is refreshed you will lose you content, so if you do anticipate on the page refreshing you will need a way in which to temporarily hold the information before it being saved.

On a side note, I'd also consider renaming your classes "MyTests" to "MyTest" (singular) and "MyQuestions" to "MyQuestion"... it's just good practice because then you'd have a List of singleton "MyQuestion" in a "MyTest". EntityFramework Codefirst will pluralise the names when the database is created/update.

Comment: Cool, I'll take your advice about the non-pluralising the class names. I will try doing this at the controller level, by having the questions submit button redirect to another page with the query ?ID=whatever, to keep track of the item in the database, perform the modifications with new method, then return to the original page with the ID so that the edit page knows what its handling.

Comment: or if i cant get it to work ill just modify it a the view level.

Comment: That certainly sounds doable. If you can post up the full code I'm sure people will be more than willing to give a hand with and point you in the direction of how you want to accomplish this :)